# Javascript removeEventListener not working on the window object

Tags: javascript, api, parallax, intersection-observer

I'm trying to create the parallax effect using the intersectionObserver API. I want the event listener to be removed from the window object when the block1 section is not intersecting. but it is not letting me remove the event for some reason

```
const obsCallBack = function (entries) {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    let scroll = window.scrollY;

    const functionParallex = () => {
      let enter = entry;
      if (enter.target.id === "block-1") {
        let offset = window.scrollY - scroll;
        portImg1.style.transform = 'translateY(' + (180 + offset * -0.30) + 'px)';
      }
    }
    if (entry.isIntersecting &&
      entry.boundingClientRect.y > 0) {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', functionParallex);
    }
    if (!entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log(entry);
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', functionParallex);
    }
  })
}
const obsOptions = {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0.01,
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(obsCallBack, obsOptions);
observer.observe(block1);
```

Comment: Every time `obsCallBack` is invoked, a totally new `functionParallex` instance will be created.  You'd be better off having some flag variable that effectively disables the event listener when you don't want it to do anything.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, that makes sense. Can you tell me a bit more how to do that with a flag variable... sorry I'm just starting out with JS

Comment: Basically `functionParallex` needs to make a decision whether to do anything or do nothing. Adding and removing event listeners is generally a clumsy way to do things. It's easier to add an event listener just once, and then have the code in the listener decide whether it should do something, or something else, or nothing.